# Implementing `hashCode()` for very simple classes

Tags: java, hashcode

I have a very simple class with only one field member (e.g. String). Is it OK to implement `hashCode()` to simply return `fieldMember.hashCode()`? Or should I manipulate the field's hash code somehow? Also, if I should manipulate it, why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If fieldMember is a pretty good way to uniquely identify the object, I would say yes.

Answer (score 10):

Joshua Bloch lays out how to properly override equals and hashCode in "Effective Java" [Chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. I had read a summary of it, but it didn't answer my question. If I follow his rules, I'll return `37 * field.hashCode() + c`, but is this really needed? Is the field's hash code not sufficient?

Comment: Assuming that the field is not a primitive.  You didn't say if it was an object or a double, so I thought the reference would be worth having.  You also didn't mention overriding equals, and you should.

Comment: The field's hash code should be sufficient. If it's a primitive, for example int:

 Integer.valueOf(fieldValue).hashCode()

Comment: @armandino: This could be a nice way to do it for primitives (except for the cost of creating a new integer for values > 127), but for an int it's sufficient to return its value. That's the implementation of Integer.hashCode(), and it makes sense because it would be perfectly distributed.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying, adding, or xor-ing things will not make it more unique. Mathematically, you'd be applying constant functions to a single variable, which does not increase the number of possible values of the variable.

That sort of technique is useful for combining multiple hashcodes and still keeping the risk of collisions relatively small; it has no bearing whatever on a single hashcode.

Comment: Thank you. I am not particularly strong in mathematics, but couldn't applying a constant function to a value enhance it (or decrease possible collisions)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by enhancement here (unless it's collision avoidance), but if two hashcodes are the same, and you do the same operation to them, they will still be equal and still collide.

Comment: For the sake of learning (regardless of Java), isn't the "static int hash(int h)" function in HashMap doing this? Avoiding collisions by applying a constant function?
https://openjdk.dev.java.net/source/browse/openjdk/jdk/trunk/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java?rev=257&view=markup

Comment: @Hosam Aly: HashMap uses the hash as an index to the array of buckets, so it uses its supplemental hash to reduce the risk of collision. This doesn't expand the number of possible hashes, but spreads the existing hash codes further apart in the bit positions that HashMap uses for indexing.

Comment: (cont.) This is why David Thornley mentioned collision avoidance in his comment above. Without hash(), a bad hashCode implementation could give the HashMap close to O(n) performance, instead of O(1). The comments on the hash() method basically say what I've been saying, but I hope I made it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's pretty standard.  And if the class reflects a database row, I just return the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two real requirements for `hashCode`: one, that `equals` instances have equal hash codes, and two, that `hashCode` runs reasonably fast.  The first requirement is the most important one in practice; without it, you could put something into a collection but not find it there.  The second is simply a performance issue.

If the hash code algorithm of your field meets the above, then its algorithm also works for your class, if your class `equals` also depends solely on whether those fields are `equals`.

Comment: You left out one requirement: Objects that are not equal usually have different hash codes.

Comment: I thought about that.  Thing is, if they have different hash codes, that's great, but if they don't, that's often fine, too (and in practice, always unavoidable).  Hash collisions just make searches a tad longer, whereas the other case is an honest-to-god failure.

Answer (score 1):

If 'fieldMember' variable already implements 'hashCode' function then you can use it directly from your parent class. If 'fieldMember' variable is a custom class instance, then you must implement it correctly by yourself. Read [java.lang.Object](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) API documentation as guideline to implement 'hashCode'.

Answer (score 0):

Ya. It is good programming practice. I normally use:

return var ^ 1;

Comment: That's the heart of my question: do I need to combine it with something else? You're xor-ing it with 1, so does this mean that the field's hash code is not sufficient?

Comment: The randomness of (var) and (var ^ 1) are the same. I wouldn't bother doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, unless you are using this object as the key for a *HashMap or an element in a *HashSet, hashCode() doesn't need to be overridden.

Comment: I expect it to be used in a HashMap, so I do need to override it.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned, you should follow the advice in Effective Java.  If you override the hashCode() method, you should also be overriding the equals() method.  Furthermore, the two methods should be consistent.

To simplify writing good equals() and hashCode() methods, I use [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from Apache Commons Lang

Here are examples:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    User other = (User) o;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(this.getUniqueId(), other.getUniqueId())
            .isEquals();
}

public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(this.getUniqueId())
            .toHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, but this is probably overkill for my simple object.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's overkill; I use this approach on all my domain classes, even the simplest ones.  And simple classes have a tendency to become more complicated over time! :)